# VBA Error asking to define variable when going through Dictionary Keys

Tags: vba, excel

VBA keeps on giving me an error message saying that the "Key" variable is not defined. However, this code used to work, and i'm unsure why it doesn't now...

The variable it highlights is "Key" on the `For Each Key In dic` line.

Why does it give me an error?

```
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Method : CreateUniqueISINList
' Purpose: Takes Array and groups it based on one criteria. The quantity data field is summed.
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Function CreateUniqueISINList(ByRef arr As Variant) As Variant
Dim dic As Dictionary
Set dic = New Dictionary

'Create dictionary with list of unique ISINs
Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
    If Not dic.Exists(arr(1, i)) Then
        dic.Add arr(1, i), arr(1, i) 'Keep ISIN
    End If
Next i

'Create output Array with relevant quantity of stocks held
Dim arrWIP
ReDim arrWIP(dic.Count, 1)

Dim j As Long
For Each Key In dic
    arrWIP(j, 0) = Key 'set ISIN
    For i = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
        If arr(1, i) = Key Then
            arrWIP(j, 1) = arrWIP(j, 1) + arr(3, i) 'update quantity
        End If
    Next i
    j = j + 1 'increase counter for arrWIP
Next Key

CreateUniqueISINList = arrWIP
Set dict = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: "However, this code used to work, and i'm unsure why it doesn't now..." I can bet about a dollar, that the Scripting library is not added.

Comment: just declare your `Key` it is good practice... forcing variables declaration is, despite `Option Explicit` a clickable option in Options, maybe you changed it?

Comment: How about `Dim Key` ?

Comment: @Vityata probably youre right, but Key is still undeclared

Comment: @Vityata Scripting Run time was already added

Comment: @avb I always use Option Explicit...

Comment: @Vityata I think you lose a dollar... it would have stopped on `Dictionary` first.

Comment: @rohrl77 - so good that I did not bet. See the answer, it should work.

Comment: @ashleedawg You were right!

Comment: @ashleedawg - right. But the built-in compilator in my brain has skipped it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dim Key` would be enough. If you want to make it a bit better looking, write `Dim Key as Variant`. It was working before, because you did not have explicitly written `Option Explicit` on the top of the module. Now, when you have written it, you have to explicitly declare each variable.

Then make sure that you are not having 2 variables with names `dic` and `dict`. This is where `Option Explicit` actually helps you write better code.

Comment: Thank you! Not sure why it did't complain when i ran that before.... maybe i accidentally deleted something... odd.

Comment: @rohrl77 - you did not delete something, you have probably added `Option Explicit` on the top.

Comment: Nope. Can't be. That is in every module i create. been programming with that for years.

Comment: @rohrl77 - then someone has deleted something.